# comparing multivariate posteriors

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

Do there exist standard methods for summarizing high-dimensional multivariate posteriors, in particular to determine how much overlap exists between two separately estimated posteriors?

The R package 'ks' provides functionality for kernel smooths in up to 6 dimensions. In a different context (designed for summarizing multivariate niche space in ecology), the R package 'hypervolume' has some potentially useful functionality (dimensionality limited only by computer power, but density estimates are thresholded to calculate volumes... in principle it looks like the threshold can be adjusted to explore the overlap between two distributions).

However, this seems like a problem for which there might already exist standard techniques/tools specific to summarizing posterior output from MCMC sampling. Any leads?